# Как вернуть файл из контроллера ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#

Мне требуется вернуть файл из контроллера. Я написал следующий код

```cs
using var fileStream = helpPageService.GetFileStream(helpPage);

var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
await fileStream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
memoryStream.Position = 0;

return File(memoryStream, "application/octet-stream", helpPage.Name);
```

Как мне сделать очистку ресурсов. Я всё копирую в memoryStream, но как его задиспоузить?

Comment: В документации написано что его не обязательно диспозить: https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream но для порядка можете добавить using

Comment: А почему `fileStream` не передавать сразу в `File`? Избавитесь от ненужного выделения памяти.

Comment: диспозить надо неуправляемые ресурсы. память относится к управляемым, файлы к неуправляемым. то, что вы возвращаете из контроллера не является файлом (т.е. его тоже диспозить не нужно). в этом смысл c#, что он освобождает разработчика от подобных задач.

Comment: Если копнуть глубже, в сами исходники, то можно найти где он сам освобождает поток файла. 
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/FileStreamResultExecutor.cs#L31
Так что ручной очистки ресурсов делать не нужно.